# Check User Authentication on HTTP Post

Tags: php, http, post

If I have a form on index.php which sends a post request to process_form.php how can I check user permissions?

For example on index.php could be a form that is only showed for administrators of the website, this form could be for example posting a news article.

What is there to prevent anyone manually crafting a post request using something like postman and sending it to process_form.php?

I am currently using PHP sessions to authenticate users so should I be sending something like the PHP session ID along with the form and checking on that within the process_form.php file?

Example of index.php

```
<form class="form" id="text_form" action="process_form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="text_field" name="text_field" class="form-control" value=""/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6"><button id="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save</button></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Example of process_form.php:

```
<?php
//Post array gets inserted to Database within this file
//Before inserting to database how can I check who submitted this form?
?>
```

Comment: Could post some code to get clear picture ??

Comment: Sessions are automatically sent with post... Well they are not send as they are actually server side data, but the session ID is sent through cookies, which is also included in POSTs. You simply just need to check your authentication in process_form.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After log-in, create session variable as "user_type = admin", in case of administrator, else set it to "normal"

**process_form.php**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Check session variables
if ( (isset($_SESSION["user_type"])) && ($_SESSION["user_type"] == "admin"))
{
   // Do your operation
}
else
{
    echo "Not allowed to post"
}
?>
```

Comment: Didn't realise this still worked for pages posted to.

Answer (score 0):

In your `process_form.php` do:

```
<?php

session_start(); // Start session first to get access to the $_SESSION vars

if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) === false && $_SESSION['admin'] === true) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Access Forbidden');
    exit;

    // Or something like that.
}
```

So you have to store the admin state in the session and check against it.